# error when downgrading mongodb 3.4 to 2.6.11

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to downgrade my local mongodb version from **3.4** to **2.6.11** in **ubuntu 14.04**, I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to start mongodb:

> 2017-01-27T10:24:16.190+0600 [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: 28574 Cannot start server. Detected data files in
>   /var/lib/mongodb created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The
>   configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating

**Here is the procedure I've followed**

**remove existing mongodb version**

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb-org mongodb-org-*
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

**install 2.6.11 version**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes mongodb-org=2.6.11 mongodb-org-server=2.6.11 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.11 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.11 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.11
```

**pin version**

```
echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

**start mongodb**

```
sudo service mongod start
```

**debugging**

```
cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

> 2017-01-27T10:24:16.190+0600 [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: 28574 Cannot start server. Detected data files in
>   /var/lib/mongodb created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The
>   configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: 2.6 does not support WirdTiger storage engine, If you want it to work you need to export your data first using mongodump and then restore it into the old version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default storage engine in 3.4 is `wiredTiger` whereas it's `mmapv1` in 2.6. Hence data from of 3.4 is not compatible with 2.6.

If your data is not important, just delete the content of data directory and you'll be fine:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/*
```

If you need the data, reinstall 3.4, backup the data using `mongodump`, downgrade to 2.6 and restore the data using `mongorestore`.

Since 3.4 supports additional data types, you may run into some compatibility issues.